# Timeout using mongoose createConnection for test with mocha

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mocha.js

I have a problem with the **mongoose.createConnection** function, here is my code for the tests:

```
"use strict";
// connect to mongodb://localhost/node_marque_test
// empty database before each test

let mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    expect = require('chai').expect,
    // use a specific base for test purposes
    dbURI = 'mongodb://localhost/node_marque_test',
    Marque = require('../lib/marque.js');

before(function(done){
  // connect to db
  let connection = mongoose.createConnection(dbURI);
  // remove all documents
  connection.on('open', function(){

    Marque.remove(function(err, marques){
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
        throw(err);
      } else {
        // console.log('cleaning marques from mongo');
        done();
      }
    })
  })
})
afterEach(function(done){
  Marque.remove().exec(done);
})

describe('an instance of Marque', ()=>{
  let marque;
  beforeEach((done)=>{
    marque = new Marque({name: 'YAMAHA'})
    marque.save((err)=>{
      if(err){throw(err);}
      done();
    })
  })
  it('has a nom', ()=>{
    expect(marque.name).to.eql('YAMAHA');
  })

  it('has a _id attribute', ()=>{
     expect(marque).to.have.property('_id')
  })
})
```

And here is the code of the **Marque** object:

```
"use strict";
let mongoose = require('mongoose'), Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Schema definition with some validation
let marqueSchema = Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true}
});

// compile schema to create a model
let Marque = mongoose.model('Marque', marqueSchema);

// custom validation rules
Marque.schema.path('name').validate(name_is_unique, "This name is already taken");

function name_is_unique(name,callback) {
    Marque.find({$and: [{name: name},{_id: {$ne: this._id}}]}, function(err, names){
        callback(err || names.length === 0);
    });
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('Marque');
```

So when i run **npm test** i got this error:

```
  1) "before all" hook

  0 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1)  "before all" hook:
     Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

But if i replace

```
// connect to db
let connection = mongoose.createConnection(dbURI);
// remove all documents
connection.on('open', function(){
```

By

```
// connect to db
mongoose.connect(dbURI);
// remove all documents
mongoose.connection.on('open', function(){
```

Everything works and the test pass :

```
  an instance of Marque
    ✓ has a nom
    ✓ has a _id attribute


  2 passing (65ms)
```

The problem is that i need to do multiples tests so i can't use **mongoose.connect** (else i got **Error: Trying to open unclosed connection.** )

So how can i use createConnection to connect to mongoose inside my tests ?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, we need to register the model schema on the connection instance. i.e use connection.model instead of mongoose.model. From [here](http://blog.blairvanderhoof.com/post/37309147906/why-arent-my-models-returning-from-their-queries)

> you need to always reference that connection variable if you include a registered model, otherwise, if you use mongoose to load the model, it will never actually talk to your database.

To address your problem, first pass the connection instance to marque.js.

```
...
let connection = mongoose.createConnection(dbURI);
Marque = require('../lib/marque.js')(connection);
...
```

and in marque.js:

```
"use strict";
let mongoose = require('mongoose'), Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Schema definition with some validation
let marqueSchema = Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true}
});

module.exports = function(conn) {
    // compile schema to create a model. Probably should use a try-catch.
    let Marque = conn.model('Marque', marqueSchema);

    // custom model validation code here
    // ...

    return conn.model('Marque');
}
```